# How to make slowly swipe animation in react native?

Tags: react-native, animation

I don't know about animation so pls guide me how to make this type of animation in react native

[splshanimation](https://www.kapwing.com/videos/64bd30a9edaa9f00d11a74c9)

| want this type of animation I hope you get this idea , pls help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Your question might be closed because it's basically asking others to write code for you. You're encouraged to make your own effort and ask here if something goes wrong. There are many resources online to learn about animations in RN.